# Unable to find a method belonging to an object

Tags: java

I believe I am making a really simple mistake/ overlooking something trivial.

```
import java.util.Comparator;

public class NaturalComparator<Integer> {

    public int compare(Integer o1, Integer o2) {
        return o1.intValue() - o2.intValue();
    }
}
```

I receive the following error when compiling.

```
NaturalComparator.java:6: error: cannot find symbol
        return o1.intValue() - o2.intValue();
                 ^
  symbol:   method intValue()
  location: variable o1 of type Integer
  where Integer is a type-variable:
    Integer extends Object declared in class NaturalComparator
NaturalComparator.java:6: error: cannot find symbol
        return o1.intValue() - o2.intValue();
                                 ^
  symbol:   method intValue()
  location: variable o2 of type Integer
  where Integer is a type-variable:
    Integer extends Object declared in class NaturalComparator
2 errors
```

Why am I unable to access the **intValue()** method in the **Integer** class?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are [shadowing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.4.1) the type `java.lang.Integer` with a type parameter variable you decided to name `Integer`.

Your code is equivalent to

```
public class NaturalComparator<T> {

    public int compare(T o1, T o2) {
        return o1.intValue() - o2.intValue();
    }
}
```

Which obviously doesn't compile since `Object` (the bound of `T`) doesn't declare a `intValue()` method.

What you want is

```
public class NaturalComparator implements Comparator<Integer> {

    @Override
    public int compare(Integer o1, Integer o2) {
        return o1.intValue() - o2.intValue();
    }
}
```

in which case `java.lang.Integer` is used as a type argument.

Answer (score 3):

You accidentally created a generic type parameter `Integer` which has nothing to do with the `Integer` class, and you didn't implement `Comparator`.  Try

```
public class NaturalComparator implements Comparator<Integer>
```

Placing an identifier in `<>` on the class declaration declares a generic type parameter, but placing an identifier in `<>` on the implements/extends clause is a passing a type argument.